# How does Dapper create an instance of the correct command class in ADO.Net?

Tags: c#, ado.net, dapper, sqlanywhere

How does Dapper create a `DbCommand`-instance of the specific `ADO.Net` driver using the `DbConnection` instance?

For example if i use `SAConnection`, how does `Dapper` create an instance of `SACommand` when querying data?

**Sample**

```
using (iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAConnection connection = 
DAL.ConnectionManager
   .GetOpenPoolConnection<iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAConnection>())
{
    connection.Execute("INSERT INTO Table1 (FallbackLanguageID, Guid) 
                        VALUES (?, ?)", new { fallbackLanguageID, newLocalizationGroup });
}
```

Comment: Dapper doesn't. ADO.NET *itself* creates the proper classes when you call  a factory method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each specific `DBConnection` implements an [`IDBConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) interface, which has a [`CreateCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbconnection.createcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Dapper just calls that.

Comment: Actually, not exactly. DbConnection *itself* is abstract. You need to call a factory method to create an actual connection class, *instead* of createing a hard-coded connection class. `CreateCommand` is a factory method too, that creates the appropriate command class.

Comment: And that's the beauty about Dapper, it uses all the inherent mechanisms to ADO so it works with any database connection implementing ADO.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What I meant by "Each `DBConnection`" was each specific provider `DBConnection`, such as `MySqlConnection` or `NpgsqlConnection`. I'll edit my post to make it clearer.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos and what is the difference about what Gediminas said? it can be a factory inside each intrinsic connection type, but it's part of the IDBConnection interface...

Comment: @Gusman there's a *huge* difference - interfaces were used in ADO 1.x and required knowing the driver type at compile time. Provider *factories*  were added in 2.0 to make data access code implementation agnostic. A "factory" inside the connection class is *not* a factory at all. The factory is *abstract* by definition. You [request a DbProviderFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactories(v=vs.110).aspx) from the list of provider factories, which you use to create connections etc. No concrete classes are used anywhere

Comment: I think we're not talking for the same, on this case IDBConnection is implemented in the *DBConnection (MySqlConnection, SqlServerConnection, etc), and the CreateCommand is implemented on the concrete class to create the correct command... Dapper what uses is the IDBConnection interface for creating the command, not a factory, it may be ADO 1.x but it's what it does.